# Redirect API Call from FE project to Localhost

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, redirect, localhost

I have a web application that have separate FE(React) and BE(.Net 6) projects running on Azure. And I want to make debugging process easier. Normally, I use Bridge to Kubernetes so that, when I go to my web site and make a call to backend side by pressing the button let's say, that request directly come to my running application on my localhost.
Now, my question is that I want to use a concept something like

I go to my web site (let's say **https://www.myexampleproject.com**) and I edit the url as

**https://www.myexampleproject.com?debug=https://localhost:3001**

As a result, my running FE application starts sending those API calls to my localhost.

This method helps me to get rid of bridge to kubernetes and do debugging in an easy way. I don't have to take the bash by selecting copy as cURL(bash) from network tab and paste it to postman and etc..

So, how can I do that simply?

Thanks in advance and I am open to alternative solutions as well.

I searched what I want here but I could not find a proper solution according to my case.